# PL/SQL Cursor Comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm a beginner when it comes to pl sql. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have created two cursors within a procedure. The first one returns product id's and the summed quantity of times that particular product was ordered from within a table called Order_Details.

The second cursor just returns product id's from a different table along with an empty column called Qty_Ordered.

I need to compare the two cursors so that when a product id is returned in BOTH cursors, the empty field in the qty_ordered column is update (next to the corresponding product id). If a product id is found in the second cursor but NOT the first, it means that product has not been ordered yet and the qty_ordered for that product should read zero.

As I said, I'm new, so please don't be too harsh. I'm not sure how this loop structure should look...

Here's what I've got:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ex5b_add_quantities
     (qty_ordered in number) is

    CURSOR ORD_CURSOR is
        SELECT PRODUCT_ID as "ID", sum (QUANTITY) as "Qty_Ordered"
        FROM ORDER_DETAILS
        group by PRODUCT_ID
        order by PRODUCT_ID;

    CURSOR PROD_CURSOR is
        SELECT PRODUCT_ID as "ID", QTY_ORDERED
        FROM Product
        group by PRODUCT_ID, QTY_ORDERED
        order by PRODUCT_ID;

BEGIN
```

Comment: Not sure what your intentions are with that parameter.

Comment: Oh geez...sorry! I was playing around with that idea and forgot to remove it before i posted this!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a loop, you want an outer join.

```
select p.product_id as ID
       , sum(nvl(o.quantity , 0)) as QTY_ORDERED
from product p
     left join order_details o
          on p.product_id = o.product_id
group by p.product_id 
order by p.product_id;
```

Check out the obligatory [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/538f8/1).

Comment: I'm not sure what this code is supposed to mean...I'm sorry my knowledge is remedial, but this query doesn't only returns errors for me when I try to execute it

Comment: Sorry, I missed the aliases in the ORDER BY and GROUP BY.